# Reactive event processing with retrying in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, events, actor, reactive-programming

I would like to implement a microservice which after receive a request (via message queue) will try to execute it via REST/SOAP calls to the external services. On success the reply should be sent back via MQ, but **on failure** the request should be **rescheduled for the execution later** (using some custom algorithm like 10 seconds, 1 minute, 10 minutes, timeout - give up). After specified amount of time the failure message should be sent back to the requester.

It should run on `Java 8` and/or `Groovy`. Event persistence is **not** required.

First I though about `Executor` and `Runnable/Future` together with `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay`, but it looks to much low level for me. The second idea was actors with `Akka` and [Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.3/java/scheduler.html) (for rescheduling), but I'm sure there could be some other approaches.

**Question**. What technique would you use for reactive event processing with an ability to reschedule them on failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have found the library [async-retry](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry/) which was written just for this purpose. It allows to asynchronously retry the execution in a very customizable way. Internally it leverages ScheduledExecutorService and [CompletableFuture](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html) (or [ListenableScheduledFuture](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) from Guava when Java 7 has to be used).

Sample usage (from the project web page):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
RetryExecutor executor = new AsyncRetryExecutor(scheduler).
    retryOn(SocketException.class).
    withExponentialBackoff(500, 2).     //500ms times 2 after each retry
    withMaxDelay(10_000).               //10 seconds
    withUniformJitter().                //add between +/- 100 ms randomly
    withMaxRetries(20);

final CompletableFuture<Socket> future = executor.getWithRetry(() ->
        new Socket("localhost", 8080)
);

future.thenAccept(socket ->
        System.out.println("Connected! " + socket)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Event" is quite fuzzy term, but most of definitions I met was talking about one of techniques of Inversion of Control. This one was characterized with fact, that you don't care WHEN and BY WHOM some piece of code will be called, but ON WHAT CONDITION. That means that you invert (or more precisely "lose") control over execution flow.

Now, you want event-driven processing (so you don't want to handle WHEN and BY WHOM), yet you want to specify TIMED (so strictly connected to WHEN) behaviour on failure. This is some kind of paradox to me.

I'd say you would do better, if you'd use callbacks for reactive programming, and on failure you'd just start new thread that will sleep for 10 seconds and re-run callback.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. TIMED is only need to delay the next attempt (using some algorithm) and I don't see a way to do it in any other way. Nevertheless the rescheduled event is later treated as any other execution (ON WHAT CONDITION - there arrived an event and need to be processed).

Comment: Btw, `thread that will sleep for 10 seconds and re-run callback` - I assume it was a shorthand and you don't want to pause a thread for 10 seconds with sleep(10000).